# Is there an easy Windows equivalent to this search in Bash?

Tags: windows, search, file-search

If I type

```
locate something | grep "someEnding$"
```

in a shell it will take a second to give me a list of every file on my system where the absolute path contains 'something' and ends 'someEnding'.

If there a way to do this in Windows? Preferably quickly, but OK if not.

Comment: The cmd equivalent is [`FindStr`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in Powershell it will be:

```ps
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *something* | Select-String "someEnding$"
```

Answer (score 0):

In powershell, it's easy to do the same.

```
# gathering files with something in the name 
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp\*something*
<# this returns 
    Répertoire : C:\temp

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                             
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                             
d-----        27/08/2021     14:16                dir with something in the name                                                                                                   
-a----        27/08/2021     14:18              9 another something file.txt                                                                                                       
-a----        27/08/2021     14:19             24 somethingfile.txt 
#>
# note that you must add -Recurse as parameter if you're looking for only on the first level
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp\*something* -Recurse
# adding -file parameter, collect only file, not directory (or sub-directories)
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp\*something* -File -Recurse
<# this returns
    Répertoire : C:\temp

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                             
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                             
-a----        27/08/2021     14:18              9 another something file.txt                                                                                                       
-a----        27/08/2021     14:19             24 somethingfile.txt     
#>
```

if you looking for a specific content, it's different

```
# 1 - collect list of file an put them in a var
$Allfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp\*.txt
# 2 - foreach loop to look for file containing specific word
foreach ($file in $Allfiles)
    {
    Get-Item -Path $file.FullName | Select-String -Pattern "something"
    }
<# I've only one file containing "something"
the return is 
C:\Temp\another something file.txt:1:something
#>
```

Windows Powershell is native on Windows, and Powershell exists in many OS.
This is a script language oriented object. The output is always an object (or a collection of objects) with properties. In the first sample, the output show 4 properties (Mode, LastWriteTime, Length, and Name) but this is the default display. There several other properties (CreationTime, Directory (parent), FUllName, LastAccessTime, Extension, Length, BaseName (name without extension...)

It's easy to manipulate and get the info, you're looking for and just this. Not only get, but modify, set, add, remove, delete, ...
Each cmdlet is build like Verb-Noun. Verb is an action verb, and noun is the context. Use Get-command to show all the cmdlets available. Yse Get-Command Get-* to show only the cmldets beginning with get-, ...